# XML format received is not well formed?? why?

Tags: java, android, asp.net, xml

I am trying to write a ASP.net Web API that sends XML files from the database and recieve/read it on android

The XML file that I send is something like this

```
<ArrayOfMerchant xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MvcApplication1.Models">
    <Merchant>
        <Address>ABC</Address>
        <City>HHHH</City>
        <Country>EEEE</Country>
        <Id>1</Id>
        <Latitude/>
        <Longitude/>
        <Name>Some store</Name>
    </Merchant>
</ArrayOfMerchant>
```

Opened on browser and it looks fine.

On the Android side I am trying to receive and read it with HttpURLConnection.
Everything works , but when I try to convert the Input-stream into string, the string is something like

```
String = [{"Id":1,"Name":"Some store","Address":"ABC","City:"EEEE","Country":"Canada","Longitude":"","Latitude":""}]
```

Question:

1)Why does it display differently with different markup and also different ordering of the elements?

2)How can I receive / retrieve it as a normal XML file so I can parse it?

Comment: Well it's clearly giving you JSON rather than XML. My guess is that either you're actually going to a different URL, or you need to include an accept header for XML.

Comment: fixed it with using accept header, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1) I dot know, depends on your ASP code and configuration. You can try to change parameters of your HTTP request to see how your ASP app respond when you change [Accept header](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields) or User-Agent. [There are some tools.](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/search/?q=http&appver=24.0&platform=windows)

2) [Actually, you don't need XML to parse the data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605913/how-to-parse-json-in-android) .